# Start new Android activity from JNI

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, java-native-interface

I managed to call a java method from JNI, but if from JNI I call a java method where there is startActivityForResult (), the activity does not start and I always have a black screen. 
In JNI that method is called inside the onMessage method.
I have implemented a socket in c++ with boost.

Can you help me? 
This is my JNI method

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/SDKCallsActivity");
        jmethodID sendHandshake = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "socketOpen", "()V");
        phase = phase + 1;
        env->CallVoidMethod(obj, sendHandshake);
```

This is my Java method

```
@Override
    public void socketOpen() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
 
        startActivityForResult(callingIntent, 1001);
    }
```

**UPDATE 2022/05/29** 
I solved the problem. The cause was that the C++ websocket in boost starts a loop and the call does not arrive at that point. In fact, by stopping the web socket, I can start the activity.
So I had to create a thread and connect the websocket in c++ in this thread. The startActivity() I do it before the creation of the thread.

Comment: have you tried to call `startActivityForResult` in main or Ui thread?

Comment: @Afshin, yes, but is the same. The call is successful, I am able to enter the socketOpen method, but the activity is not opened. Black screen